# Word Interop spellchecking a document word by word is too slow

Tags: interop, ms-word, spell-checking

With the code below basically I'm checking a document word by word and separate the correct ones. I works, but too slow that I have to wait for more than 10 minutes for 40 thousand words. When I open the same document word checks it in a few seconds. What am I doing wrong?

```
var application = new Application();
        application.Visible = false;
        Document document = application.Documents.Open("C:\\Users\\hrzafer\\Desktop\\spellcheck.docx");

        // Loop through all words in the document.
        int count = document.Words.Count;
        IList<string> corrects = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            if (document.Words[i].SpellingErrors.Count == 0)
            {
                string text = document.Words[i].Text;
                corrects.Add(text);
            }
        }

        File.WriteAllLines("corrects.txt", corrects);
        application.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

a workaround, as it seems you only want the correct words in your document:

```
for i=ActiveDocument.Range.SpellingErrors.Count to 1 step -1
    ActiveDocument.Range.SpellingErrors(i).Delete
next
```

then save the document with a new name

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="C:\MyWordDocs\NewFile.docx", _ 
    FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
```